# Material Design Tablet Component Issue

Tags: material-design, tablet

I am trying to convert my tablet wireframes into material design UI's and I am confused on a few parts on how to translate some components to material design components. I have looked all over but it's became difficult to find a good resource for tablet not mobile.

Here is my problem:

I am confused on how to translate this into material design for tablet. I saw the component "Stepper", but I am confused on how to start off. The goal of the UX is to do a step-by-step checklist.

If anyone knows of any good resources I can take a look at, that would be great.

Comment: You should add an image or two of what you have done already and what you want to achieve. The question is hard to understand as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will indeed need to use a stepper, so [here](https://material.io/guidelines/components/steppers.html#steppers-usage) is a page to check out. Also, a great example of a Material Design stepper can be found in the [Status](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.james.status&hl=en) app for Android. I hope this helps!